# Call recordings in Windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio-recording

Is it possible in windows phone 7 application to record conversation during incoming or outgoing call and save it somewhere inside the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. You can vote for it [in the Windows Phone wish list](https://windowsphone7community.uservoice.com/forums/84435-feature-feedback/suggestions/2002355-record-voice-calls).

Comment: Why post the same answer, just with a link, instead of just supplying the link as a comment to the other answer? Silly!

Comment: @Claus I am absolutely with you that we should support answers which at least try to provide some explanation or evidence.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.